# How to exit from ssh session created from bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

I have the following bash script `test.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" user@$1
#do some stuff
exit
```

However if I run this script `./test.sh` I need to enter **ctrl+d** to get out of the ssh session and it appears as if the `exit` command is not working the way I intended.

Is there any way I can exit this ssh session that was created from this bash script?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You may want to code a [here document](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html)

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" user@$1 << ENDHERE
   here do some remote stuff
   also here
   exit
ENDHERE
```

If you code `<<-ENDHERE` the initial spaces or tabs in each line of the here document are suppressed. Parameters (like `$foo`) are substituted unless you code `<<\ENDHERE`, and the `ENDHERE` can actually be any word, conventionally in capitals.

Read the [Advanced Bash Scripting guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/) (which does have some imperfections)

Comment: also use ssh -T if you don't want a tty

Comment: if you want to exit the shell script if the ssh session is interrupted, add `exec` before `ssh`.

Comment: There are some problems with the HERE Implementation. For one, you can't sudo through HERE documentation. See the end of http://thornelabs.net/2013/08/21/simple-ways-to-send-multiple-line-commands-over-ssh.html for more information.